# Does the parameter of Observable.create() function have to define explicitely an observer?

Tags: javascript, observable, subscribe

I came across this code from here:  https://medium.com/@mohandere/rxjs-5-in-5-minutes-1c3b4ed0d8cc

```
function multiplyByTen(input) {
  var output = Rx.Observable.create(function subscribe(observer) {
    input.subscribe({
      next: (v) => observer.next(10 * v),
      error: (err) => observer.error(err),
      complete: () => observer.complete()
    });
  });
  return output;
}

var input = Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4]);
var output = multiplyByTen(input);
output.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
// Result In:
// 10 
// 20 
// 30 
// 40
```

I just do not see where the "observer" parameter for the subscribe function inside the multiplyByTen function comes from? Does it have to be explicitely defined or is it just some "default" object that gets passed to the create function in case it was not defined before? And why is it called function subscribe(observer) inside the function? Does it override the default .subscribe() function or could it also be an anonymous function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just an RxJS construct  to allow you to dispatch new values to the subscriber functions. Basically, this is how RxJS have designed the library to work. This allows you to control the dispatch of new values. One example of usage is when you have some asynchronous operation and you want to send a new value to the subscribers when it has resolved/completed.

You can read more about how it works here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/create.html

Also, check out this simple synchronous example in JsBin (taken from the docs link above)

```
/*
  Create an observable that emits 'Hello' and 'World' on  
  subscription.
*/
const hello = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
  observer.next('Hello');
  observer.next('World');
});

const subscribe = hello.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
// prints.. the follwoing:
// Hello
// World
```

The asynchronous case I mentioned above is portrayed here: (from official RxJS jsBin examples - https://jsbin.com/lodilohate/1/edit?js,console):

```
// RxJS v6+
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

/*
  Increment value every 1s, emit even numbers.
*/
const evenNumbers = Observable.create(function(observer) {
  let value = 0;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (value % 2 === 0) {
      observer.next(value);
    }
    value++;
  }, 1000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
});
//output: 0...2...4...6...8
const subscribe = evenNumbers.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
//unsubscribe after 10 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  subscribe.unsubscribe();
}, 10000);
```

Comment: ok, I think I see how it works, and that an observer is just an object with next(), err() and complete() function, but I just don't understand where the "observer" parameter object comes from when it was not defined previously, is it already defined as default in the Observable from rxjs library or so?

Comment: You're using the Rx.js library, that gives you the following function:
`Observable.create()`. As you correctly noticed, `create` expects a function that has a parameter `observer`. Simply put, `create` will inject this `observer` object into the function that you pass - and this way you can use `next()`, `err()` and `complete()` functions. Thus, it's simply how they've designed the flow/injection/way to use these useful functions.

Comment: ok, I wanted to know more about the inner workings, found a nice article here: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/rxjs-observables-observers-operators  but I am still not sure how it implicitely works to pass the observer around into other functions, I am also not quite sure if I understood those returned functions that were returned from inside "return new Observable()" functions ... its quite confusing -.- but I guess thats rather core javascript problems...

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a "problem" - perhaps you might want to read into how core JavaScript works itself. JavaScript allows you to pass objects (functions are objects) and primitive values. Another key concept of injecting, exposing objects and passing them around is _currying_. Might help understand how they achieve this.

Comment: _'but I am still not sure how it implicitely works to pass the observer around into other functions'_ 
- You're a consumer of the Observable class. Observable.create(...) & new Observable(...) do the same thing - ie. `create` is an alias for the constructor. 
- So to use this mechanism - you call the constructor and you pass a function to it. Your function takes the `observer`. The internals of the Observable class has the observer, and now also has your function. They simply call your function and pass the observer into it - `yourFn(observer)`. And `yourFn` uses those observer functions.

Comment: But let's revisit the basic usage of Observable pattern..Let's say you have a function `payCashier()`. To complete this action you need to wait for the cashier to `completeOrder()`. `completeOrder` is asynchronous, so 
you want to be notified when that finishes. So you decide to use the Observable pattern.

 `const obs = Observable.create(observer => { // this is your function
completeOrder().then(() => observer.next(someValueIfYouWant))
}
obs.subscribe((someValueIfYouWant) => payCashier());`
Apologies, comments only have a character limit, so I had to keep it brief..

Comment: @user2774480 would you accept anwser if it has helped at all? Thanks.

Comment: ok it didnt add anything to clarify the internals of javascript for this example or the behaviour of that observer in particular I think, but it clarifies other things..